# Adding tap functionality to ColorSprites

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Making a Texas Hold'Em app. This is my first time working in sprite-kit. My current problem is that I have the cards as Color Sprite objects.

[image]

This is the GameScene with the cards. Ignore the five cards on the top. I only want the bottom two to have the flip functionality.

My goal is for the user to be able to tap one of their cards and it will flip from the back of the card, to the card in their hand and vice versa. My current strategy is using this `override func touchesBegan`.

The array playerOne is the cards for playerOne. 
The cardOne and cardTwo are the cards for the playerOne.
FlippedOne and flippedTwo are keeping track of which card is currently flipped. This way the cards would flip individually.
This same concept is repeated if there is multiple players.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if (playerCount == 0 && turn == 0) {
        let cardOne = playerOne[0].getNum()
        let cardTwo = playerOne[1].getNum()
        var flippedOne = 0
        var flippedTwo = 0
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if (playerCardOne.frame.contains(location) && flippedOne == 0) {
                playerCardOne.texture = cardTextures[cardOne]
                flippedOne = 1
            }
            if (playerCardOne.frame.contains(location) && flippedTwo == 1) {
                playerCardOne.texture = back
                flippedOne = 0
            }
            if (playerCardTwo.frame.contains(location) && flippedTwo == 0) {
                playerCardTwo.texture = cardTextures[cardTwo]
                flippedTwo = 1
            }
            if (playerCardTwo.frame.contains(location) && flippedTwo == 0) {
                playerCardTwo.texture = back
                flippedTwo = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there is a better way of making the cards flip on tap, I am open to ideas.
My thought on why this is not working is because it's an override function. 
What currently happens is that I can get one of the cards to flip from the back to the actual card face. After which I cannot get either card to flip.

Comment: @Doug that offers no solution to his problem, all that presents is a different way detecting which object was touched, which his way is already working fine for that.

Comment: Derp! Didn't read it properly. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

the issue with why you can't repeatedly run the code is because you are resetting the flippedOne and flippedTwo variables every time touches began gets fired

Move the variables out to the scene and it will work fine.

I also recommend converting them to Bool for simplicity

Also you don't need the frame property when checking if the spriteNode contains a location

Also brackets around the if statement aren't required in Swift (you must've come from a different language to Swift)

```
private var flippedOne = false
private var flippedTwo = false

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let location = touch!.location(in: self)

    if card1.contains(location) {
        if flippedOne {
            card1.texture = back
            flippedOne = false
        }
        else {
            card1.texture = cardTextures[cardOne]
            flippedOne = true
        }
    }

    if card2.contains(location) {
        if flippedTwo {
            card2.texture = back
            flippedTwo = false
        }
        else {
            card2.texture = cardTextures[cardTwo]
            flippedTwo = true
        }
    }
}
```

The if statements in the touches began func can be further simplified as such...

```
if card1.contains(location) {
    card1.texture = flippedOne ? back : cardTextures[cardOne]
    flippedOne = !flippedOne
}

if card2.contains(location) {
    card2.texture = flippedTwo ? back : cardTextures[cardTwo]
    flippedTwo = !flippedTwo
}
```